# How can I switch to the standard desktop in Ubuntu Karmic?

Tags: ubuntu-9.10, netbook, switch, desktop-environments

I installed Ubuntu Karmic Koala (9.10) on my ASUS 900 netbook, and I prefer the standard interface when using it. However, I can't seem to find the actual program or utility that lets me switch between the two options. I remember having seeen it in pre-release versions of Karmic Koala, however, I can't find it.

Comment: What two options? What is the "standard interface"? And what is the one you are using now?

Comment: If you mean GNOME, then just install the meta-package gnome-desktop (or ubuntu-desktop). After that you should be able to select the Gnome Session at the Login-Screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily convert the Netbook Remix version to the standard Ubuntu desktop and it will still run perfectly on your netbook.

Go to the System menu and run Synaptic Package Manager.

Install ubuntu-desktop.

Search for "remix" and completely remove all related software packages.

Reboot.

Enjoy!

Caution: I have not tested this method fully.  Try it at your own risk.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like the package you need is called [desktop-switcher](http://www.liliputing.com/2009/02/how-to-quickly-switch-ubuntu-netbook-remix-interface-on-and-off.html).

Comment: so if you want to have both and be able to switch back and forth it looks like you'll need to...

* follow the instructions for adding the right repository here: http://www.ubuntumini.com/2008/10/installing-ubuntu-netbook-remix.html

* 'sudo aptitude install desktop-switcher' should work after that.

Answer (score 2):

The interface switcher that allows changing between Netbook Remix and Standard Desktop was mistakenly left off the installation CD. The package is in the repositories. Some nice user will come in behind me and add the name of the package here.

Answer (score 1):

Because of some stability issues, the Desktop Switcher was left out for Karmic Koala. It will probably be available in some time, but not at the moment (unless you do it your self).